# Dumping Terraform output to a local file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create a file (`credentials.json`) within a directory, say `content` using Terraform.

The contents will be the output of a private service account key.

I am using the following code to create the service account and get its key to `data`:

```
resource "google_service_account" "my-account" {
  account_id = "${var.account_id}"
  project    = "${var.project_id}"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "my-account" {
  service_account_id = "${google_service_account.my-account.name}"
}

data "google_service_account_key" "my-account" {
  name            = "${google_service_account_key.cd.name}"
  public_key_type = "TYPE_X509_PEM_FILE"
}
```

How can I then dump it to a local file?

My use case is that I want to create the `credentials.json` to enable periodic [backups](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins#backup) of `jenkins` to a google cloud storage bucket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`local_file` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/r/file.html) to write data to disk in a Terraform run.

So you could do something like the following:

```
resource "google_service_account" "my-account" {
  account_id = "${var.account_id}"
  project    = "${var.project_id}"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "my-account" {
  service_account_id = "${google_service_account.my-account.name}"
}

resource "local_file" "key" {
  filename = "/path/to/key/output"
  content  = "${base64decode(google_service_account_key.my-account.private_key)}"
}
```

Note that you should never need a data source to look at the outputs of a resource you are creating in that same Terraform command. In this case you can ditch the `google_service_account_key` data source because you have the resource available to you.

The benefit of data sources is when you need to look up some generated value of a resource either not created by Terraform or in a different state file.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be to create output for your service account:

```
output "google_service_account_key" {
  value = "${base64decode(data.google_service_account_key.my-account.private_key)}"
}
```

With the `terraform output` command you can then query specifically for the key, combined with jq (or another json parser) to find the correct output:

```
terraform output -json google_service_account_key | jq '.value[0]' > local_file.json
```

Comment: thank you, nice one but I would like the file creation to be also part of the `terraform` execution

Comment: Thanks, I just used: `terraform output -raw google_service_account_key > local_file.json`